# How to disable debug logs in spring

Tags: java, spring

How to disable debug mode in my spring application. When i run my application in production it gives lot of debug logs statements and tomcat's log file take more space in disk. like below,

```
05:03:26.340 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
05:03:26.340 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/myRestCall/1234'; against '/'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CustomUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
05:03:30.118 [http-bio-1880-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /myRestCall/1234 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original
```

Here is my depedency

```
            <!-- logging into console -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>           
    </dependency>
```

How to disable all debug logs and I want to show only warning and exception logs.

Based on result I created logback.xml(src/main/resources/config/logback.xml) file like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

But Still DEBUG logs printing in console. Where am i doing mistake?

Comment: What did you try? Looks like log4j configuration

Comment: It looks like you are using a log4j to slf4j bridge. Whats the actual logging framework in use log4j / logback / JUL. Post the configuration file for your logging framework

Comment: @ekemchitsiga pls see my updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere (usually in the classpath), you have a `logback.xml` [configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) file for this application, edit it and add

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="WARNING"/>
```

before

```
<root level="XXX">
```

Also note that you should probably ["rotate" your log files](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) to reduce disk usage.

Comment: The file **has to be** in `src/main/resources` as indicated in the doc: http://logback.qos.ch/faq.html#configFileLocation